# fiscal area in the supplier information tab of the purchase order

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb, acumos

Could you help me, I am changing the tax area code by adaptation, however the taxes are not updated, what am I missing or how can I change the related taxes when I change the tax area?

This is my code, through this event that I'm doing.

```
protected void POLine_SiteID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
        var row = (POLine)e.Row;
        var head = Base.Document.Current;
        if (head == null) return;
        if (row != null && row.OrderType == POOrderType.RegularOrder)
        {

     POLine line = PXSelect<POLine, Where<POLine.orderType,
                            Equal<Required<POLine.orderType>>,
                            And<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderType, row.OrderNbr);

            bool? xchange = false;
            if (line != null)
            {
                INSite site = PXSelect<INSite, Where<INSite.siteID,
                              Equal<Required<INSite.siteID>>>>.Select(Base, line.SiteID);
                if (site != null && line.SiteID == site.SiteID)
                {
                    var ext = site.GetExtension<INSiteExt>();
                    if (ext != null)
                    {
                        head.TaxZoneID = ext.UsrTaxZone;
                        xchange = true;
                    }
                }
                if (xchange == true)
                {
                    foreach (PEMclTaxZone zone in PXSelect<PEMclTaxZone,
                    Where<PEMclTaxZone.taxZoneID, Equal<Required<PEMclTaxZone.taxZoneID>>,
                     And<PEMclTaxZone.taxCategoryID, Equal<Required<PEMclTaxZone.taxCategoryID>>>>>.Select(Base, head.TaxZoneID, line.TaxCategoryID))
                    {
                        if (zone != null)
                        {
                            foreach (POTaxTran potax in PXSelect<POTaxTran,
                                Where<POTaxTran.orderType, Equal<Required<POTaxTran.orderType>>,
                                And<POTaxTran.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POTaxTran.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(Base, head.OrderType, head.OrderNbr))
                            {
                                if (potax != null)
                                {

                                    potax.TaxID = zone.Taxid;
                                    potax.TaxZoneID = zone.TaxZoneID;
                                    Base.Taxes.Cache.Update(potax);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I select the tax area manually, two elements are registered in the tax grid, if I do it by event it only updates the last one, I follow it by code and I see that if it updates, however, it does not reflect in the tax grid.

Here I show evidence, with images.
This step is with an event that is not working.

step 1
[image]

step 2:

[image]

step 3:

[image]

manually select the tax area, selected from the same tab.
step 1:

[image]

step 2:

That's how it should go, that's what I want the event to do.

[image]

Please tell me what I am failing in the event, I hope I have been clear, thanks.

Comment: I think most of the Tax logic for documents are in tax extensions. See if you can find one for purchase order and extend it and make your changes there.

Comment: You will not have a small example, it would help me a lot and thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that grab these are the Tax Zone Extensions. You would want to override the GetDefaultTaxZone function of POOrderEntry

```
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual string GetDefaultTaxZone(POOrder row,
       Func<POOrder, string> baseMethod)
    {
        //logic before base function
        baseMethod(row);
        //logic after base function
    }
```

If you do not want any of the code to be run, feel free to copy the initial function and do not call the baseMethod delegate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, I will try and inform you of the result.